# Incrementing score in react quiz app (multivariable score)

Tags: json, reactjs

I am creating quiz app in react.js. Question: how to increment total score not only by 1 but also by 3, 4 (each answer should have unique score)
question bank:
let qBank = [
{
question: "I plan to begin withdrawing money from my investments in:",
options: ["Less than 3 years", "3-5 years", "6-10 years", "11 years or more"],
answer:"3-5 years",
id:"0"
},
{
question: "Once I begin withdrawing funds from my investments, I plan to spend all of the funds in:",
options: ["Less than 2 years", "2-5 years", "6-10 years", "11 years or more"],
answer:"2-5 years",
id:"1"
},
{
question: "I would describe my knowledge of investments as:",
options: ["None", "Limited", "Good", "Extensive"],
answer:"None",
id:"2"
}

etc

and code itself:

```
nextQuestionHandler = () => {

    const { userAnswer, answers, score } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1
    })
    //increment the score if answer is correct
    if (userAnswer === answers) {
        this.setState({
            score: score + 1
        })
    }
}

//update the component
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { currentQuestion } = this.state;
    if (this.state.currentQuestion !== prevState.currentQuestion) {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                disabled: true,
                questions: qBank[currentQuestion].question,
                options: qBank[currentQuestion].options,
                answers: qBank[currentQuestion].answer
            };
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `value` attribute to the questions stored in `qBank`.

```js
let qBank = [ 
  { 
    question: "I plan to begin withdrawing money from my investments in:", 
    options: ["Less than 3 years", "3-5 years", "6-10 years", "11 years or more"], 
    answer:"3-5 years", 
    value: 1,
    id:"0" 
  }, 
  { 
    question: "Once I begin withdrawing funds from my investments, I plan to spend all of the funds in:", 
    options: ["Less than 2 years", "2-5 years", "6-10 years", "11 years or more"], 
    answer:"2-5 years", 
    value: 2,
    id:"1" 
  }, 
  { question: "I would describe my knowledge of investments as:", 
    options: ["None", "Limited", "Good", "Extensive"], 
    answer:"None", 
    value: 3,
    id:"2" 
  }
]

nextQuestionHandler = () => {

    const { userAnswer, answers, score, value } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1
    })
    //increment the score if answer is correct
    if (userAnswer === answers) {
        this.setState({
            score: score + value
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! do you know how can i add different value ton each of the option?

Comment: Yes, you can make your `options` an array of objects like `[{"name": "None", value: 4"}, {"name": "Limited", value: 2"}, ...]` or you can make it an array of paired values like `[["None", 4], ["Limited", 2], ...]` where the first item is the name of the option, and the second is the value.

Comment: thanks AJ! will try that. thanks for taking time and answering that!

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to mark the question as answered for future users

Comment: hey AJ, I know I am asking to much, but maybe you can have a look at the following question, which is follow up on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498728/building-quiz-app-in-reactjs-cant-figure-out-how-to-update-the-score-based-on

Answer (score 1):

You can look to add an extra attribute to each question.

eg.

```
{ question: "I would describe my knowledge of investments as:", options: ["None", "Limited", "Good", "Extensive"], answer:"None", id:"2", value: 3 }
```

and then update the score:

```
if (userAnswer === answers) {
        this.setState({
            score: score + currentQuestion.value
    })
}
```